# Getting mysql slow query report from 20 GB file

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get slow query report from mysql generated slow query log. I tried myprofi but unfortunately my windows server keep crashing when I run myprofi php script.

I also tried perl script mysqlsla from hackmysql.com but I can't seem getting it worked it gives me following error:

`Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"HOME"} in concatenation (.) or string at mysqlsla-2.03 line 2281`

I have no experience of Perl so I can't get it fixed. What are other options for parsing large mysql log file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to edit the perl script to fix this. Perl is just asking for an environment variable that it can't find. All you have to do is define that variable... and maybe a few others. You cand find the list of environment variables you need to define and what they should contain here:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/environment-variables.html

If that variable is already set, the problem is likely a permissions issue, and you need to make sure the script is executed as a user that has rights to read those variables... but I think that scenario is unlikely.